# What is the difference between server port 1099 and 4447?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

I am new to EJB3.x and JBoss so this is probably a real basic question. I've done this tutorial before and it works fine http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-7-1/ . I read in the literature that for this kind of work the port 1099 for the Naming Service is used, instead of the port 4447, which is for the HA JRMP.

So I tried the port 1099 too and it doesnt work. It seems that the JBoss server didn't opened that port. I used TCPView and telnet to check it.

I imagine the following question:

1) Why can I use the port 4447 instead of 1099?

2) Why doesn't the JBoss server try to open and use the port 1099?

The code is exactly the same as in the example und the configuration of the JBoss server has not been changed.

Comment: If they ever used 1099 for anything other than the RMI Registry they shouldn't have, as it was reserved for that at IANA in 1995. And the RMI Registry isn't a full-blown naming service.

Answer (score 1):

From the JBoss 7 documentation here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference

> "AS 7.1 supports two different types of remote JNDI. The old jnp based
>   JNDI implementation used in previous JBoss versions is no longer
>   supported."

The two types are **remote** and **ejb**.

For the remote, it explains:

> "The remote: protocol uses the JBoss remoting protocol to lookup items
>   from the servers local JNDI."

So JBoss 7 does not listen on (HA)JNDI ports anymore.

More information on remote EJB invocation is given here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Answer (score 0):

I have used`Jboss 4.0,4.3,5.0` and for each of these `1099` is `JNDI` Port.
You can find out which ports are used for which service in `server.xml` which is located in `config` directory of jboss.

Comment: I've only found a file named standalone.xml which has the following port definitions:

   <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
   <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
   <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
   <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
   <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
   <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
   <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>


The JBoss 7.1 seems to be different.

Comment: @Amit jboss 7x has a changed directory structure (they say for the better ;) , there is no server.xml anymore but rather separate configs in the according folders

Comment: @kostja Now I will have spend one more weekend to get acquainted with it :-(

Comment: @AmitDeshpande Maybe you have the answer for this question after that weekend :-)